# Downloading restarts every time after restarting Steam

Tags: steam, dota-2

I've been downloading DoTA 2 for the past 2 weeks. When I first started downloading, my electricity was cut and my computer got shut down. The next day, when I restarted my PC, the progress has jumped from 45% (which was the point it was at when the power cut occured) back to 0%. From that day on, jumps back to 0% happened every time my computer was shut down from the power cut.

I have deleted and reinstalled everything (Steam and DoTA 2) many times.
Over four days, I have used 60GB of internet to download it and the points of progress it has restarted at are: 45%, 92%, 38% and 56%.

Comment: May I ask, what is your internet speed? And based on the 'power-cuts' you're getting, how frequently do they happen and how long do the power stay up for?

Comment: my internet speed is 60kpbs and power-cuts can be any time like 3pm to 6pm  10am to 3pm, 4am to 6am, 11pm to 12pm,

Comment: http://prntscr.com/4swebi u can see here im downloading it again because i like to play dota very much :(

Comment: Yes, I can see you're downloading. But it's the behind-the-scenes that isn't favoring you. You see, when your download restarts, Steam sees that the file isn't fully completed. So, it redownloads it. Because DoTA comes in one huge package - You have to download it all in one go (NO RESTARTS).

Comment: I recommend to run chkdsk on your drives. Probably some bad sectors or file system errors due to the outage. I recommend `chkdsk /F /B <drive letter>`

Answer (score 1):

This is not only dota-2 problem but it happens with every game. Each time a power cut occurs steam starts to download the game files again.

There are two ways to solve your issue -

1. Pause the download:- if you pause the download in progress before the power cut, it will surely resume from the stage you paused it.
2. Restore/backup:- steam also offers another way to your problem. Download from the internet or take a latest backup of dota-2 from your friend in a pen drive and just restore it.

Answer (score 0):

@amit, as others have already noted, there is no "solution" per se for your problem. I suggest you try a simple workaround. [As I've already stated here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/183831/57416), you can paste the game files anywhere on your PC and when installing it on steam you just choose the folder they're in.

So, if you can get a copy of Dota 2 installation files (not the package, but the already installed game) you could install without downloading (it would still check all of your files, but it should be way faster).

If you don't know anyone with the game installed I suggest you try ciber cafes or ask online for someone to upload a torrent of it.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, DoTA is only about 20GB.
Secondly, your download constantly restarts (well, backtracks; progress jumps) because when your computer power goes out (assuming it's the instant-powercut-and-everything-goes-black-and-the-system-suddenly-shuts-off type of power cut), Steam doesn't have a chance to properly finish finish downloading the file it is patching. Because of this, when the system restarts, Steam checks for the progress and will think the file it was patching is corrupted (not properly and fully downloaded). From there, it will restart downloading that file.
Usually, Steam downloads several files at once, which explains why there are big jumps.

Also, don't delete anything (not even use the "Uninstall" button in Steam) whilst something isn't downloading properly. Let Steam manage that; it automatically scans for any corrupted/incorrect files and delete/redownload/reaquire them.
Deleting/uninstalling will only mean it will have to redownload everything again. from scratch, which is the same as hindering your progress.

---

If you are constantly suffering power problems and cannot keep your computer on long enough to download all the files, you should consider not downloading DoTA as it contains lots of large files (and thus mean you'll be very likely to have a power cut before Steam manages to fully download a single file). Or instead, switch to battery power, if you have it.
Pausing the download and quitting before the power-cut (if you know when it happens) will also help as Steam will be able to leave off from the point that you paused it at.

Comment: i did this i did shut down my pc before power cut and with this i reched till 92% but then power-cut again and power-cut is not fixed  it took 3 nights to reach till 92% power cut be mostly in day but not fixed some times it be in night ...... my internet speed is 60kbps i can't download it in one day

Comment: Your internet speed is 60kbps - Mine is ~35kbps (which is terrible and ironic because I'm in Australia). DoTA took a whole week to download. All I can suggest is that you need to get power-cuts less frequent, as during that time of power, Steam did not have enough time to finish downloading a single file. So, when a power cut/system shutdown came - It restarts downloading that file again. DoTA 2 (when downloaded) is packaged as a big giant file that Steam unpacks. That's why you have to download it in one single run (no interruptions in-between), though it used to be not like that...

Comment: thanx for ur answer bro . but it doesn't help much...... dota should make a system like torrent no effect of power-cut on downloading in torrents files

Comment: They should, but that's besides the point. If the **only** way to download Dota 2 right now is to do it in one sitting then that is the answer. The fact that *you* can't do that is also besides the point. Sometimes the right answer won't help you, but that doesn't make it any less right.

Comment: DoTA 2 was only about 6-8 GB I thought? I finished downloading it within a few hours last time at only 120 Kbps...

Comment: Says 21GB for me... Uncompressed, which is around 16GB the last time I did a full redownload. http://gyazo.com/792e1a43c0f5feb8bfb4bfcc05a74176

Comment: @amit (Didn't actually see that you were talking about Torrent files) Torrent files download differently to Steam. When something is torrented, a file (or multiple files) is/are split into chunks (or parts), most of them about 10MB each and then distributed. After downloading these 'chunks', [whatever torrent program you use] will then reassemble these 'chunks' into proper files. Steam on the other hand downloads a file as a whole, similar to web browsers.

Comment: after changing user account control it working im downloading it and after 2 power-cut it still resuming download (im very happy) :D

Answer (score -2):

I can't say for sure this will fix it, but I'd suggest:

1. Exit Steam.
2. Delete or rename Steam's `ClientRegistry.blob` file (usual location: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\ClientRegistry.blob`)
3. Start Steam.

This forces Steam to recheck which games it considers to be installed.

Comment: This file is not used any more since like 1 year.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness The file still exists and the copy on my system was last modified on September 9, 2014, which is less than a month ago.

Comment: But the file is now only 1kb big as opposed to 50 megabytes back then.

Comment: Actually, it's still used to store credentials. Computer identification etc. however are stored in the computer's registry. Game information is nowadays stored in .../SteamApps/[this folder]; just two folders back from where the game cache files.

Comment: im download it i have reached at 38% and after changing uac it resuming if it will happen again i will try ur no.2 option

Answer (score -2):

after changing fire wall settings and user account control settings and my dota resuming .......... i found this suggestion somewhere else but thank u all guys for ur help .....http://prntscr.com/4thpx1  i have downloaded 82% now and after 3 power-cuts it still resuming....

Comment: What suggestion are you following?  You should post that information here so that others can benefit from what you've found.

Comment: Please post how you achieved this, as I am currently facing this problem. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -2):

The only option is to continue downloading your game without any breaks. If you have low KBPS consider replacing your internet

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate?